# What does the value of bitcoins depend on?

Tags: value, price-volatility, inflation

I've been looking up stuff about bitcoins for some time now and i have two question stuck in my mind:

How is the value of bitcoins so unstable?

And can there be bitcoin inflation?

Answer (score 1):

The value is unstable because it's a small and speculative market.

People don't really understand what bitcoin is and they can be lead to believe many things.

Answer (score 0):

Conventional currencies are usually backed by gold that determines their value but bitcoin is different. It doesn't have any intrinsic worth, just like the paper a dollar is made of, its value depends on how much people are willing to pay to get them and how much merchants value them as a payment.
Inflation is usually caused by putting too much money on the market and thus lowering its price. Bitcoins are put in the market in a regulated way and have a cap of 21 millions, so the only way to cause inflation is a drop in demand of bitcoins.

Comment: *Conventional currencies are usually backed by gold that determines their value*: if by "conventional" here you mean "prior to the 1970s".  The world went off the gold standard around that time.